# Question about a proof in Junod's paper about the Blum-Blum-Shub generator

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I am reading [Junod's paper about the Blum-Blum-Shub generator](http://www.cs.miami.edu/home/burt/learning/Csc609.062/docs/bbs.pdf). There is one thing I just do not understand about his proof of Lemma 4. On page 17  he writes:

> We conclude that $x=-x_0$ and from Lemma 1 we know that $x \ne x_0$
>
> (So far I understand.)
>
> , so they must have different parities **(Why is this the case?)**, $n$ beeing odd, which is a contradiction.

Could you please explain that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_0$ is odd, then $-x_0 = n - x_0$ must be even (and versa-visa).